# How to delete get'ed files using SFTP on an Ubuntu server?

Tags: sftp

I putty across to two different Ubuntu servers (A and B). I would like to SFTP from A to B and `get` all the files in a directory in B to A and delete the files in B straight after the download - so that only A has the files.

How can achieve `get` files and delete the file straight after a successful transfer/download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to remove remote files:

```
rm [path]
```

and for remote directories:

```
rmdir [path]
```

Where you replace `[path]` with your actual path or file name or directory name. This as well can be wildcards as you are used to in normal terminal. for recursively getting directories you might need the `-r` flag.

Sadly there is no command for moving the files from B to A so you need to get the files from B to A and then remove the files on B. means there is no command to concatenate the get and the remove together.

For getting and then deleting the files in bulk you can use wildcards.

Example (let's assume you have your files inside a folder XY on your server B):

```bsh
# log into server A via putty/ssh
ssh user@A
# then sftp to B from A
sftp user@B
# now you will get a prompt for sftp which I will not
# repeat in the commands to follow
sftp>
# navigate to your local target directory on server A 
lcd pathtotarget/
# navigate to your source directory on server B
cd XY
# get all the files from B to A 
get *
# after the transfer is done you can go on and remove the files on B
cd ..
rmdir XY
# or if you want only the files being deleted
rm *
# quit your sftp session
quit
# log off from server A
logout
```

> The [command set available on SFTP](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sftp.1.html):
>
> ```
> bye                                Quit sftp
> cd path                            Change remote directory to 'path'
> chgrp grp path                     Change group of file 'path' to 'grp'
> chmod mode path                    Change permissions of file 'path' to 'mode'
> chown own path                     Change owner of file 'path' to 'own'
> df [-hi] [path]                    Display statistics for current directory or
>                                    filesystem containing 'path'
> exit                               Quit sftp
> get [-afPpRr] remote [local]       Download file
> reget [-fPpRr] remote [local]      Resume download file
> reput [-fPpRr] [local] remote      Resume upload file
> help                               Display this help text
> lcd path                           Change local directory to 'path'
> lls [ls-options [path]]            Display local directory listing
> lmkdir path                        Create local directory
> ln [-s] oldpath newpath            Link remote file (-s for symlink)
> lpwd                               Print local working directory
> ls [-1afhlnrSt] [path]             Display remote directory listing
> lumask umask                       Set local umask to 'umask'
> mkdir path                         Create remote directory
> progress                           Toggle display of progress meter
> put [-afPpRr] local [remote]       Upload file
> pwd                                Display remote working directory
> quit                               Quit sftp
> rename oldpath newpath             Rename remote file
> rm path                            Delete remote file
> rmdir path                         Remove remote directory
> symlink oldpath newpath            Symlink remote file
> version                            Show SFTP version
> !command                           Execute 'command' in local shell
> !                                  Escape to local shell
> ?                                  Synonym for help
> ```

Comment: In terms of speed - is it faster to `get [directory]`  - or `get` all the files _individually_ within that `[directory]`?

Comment: It's actually both the same speed because the packets are one size and the data amount does not change.